# using Regex how get the below values

Tags: python

I am trying to use regular expression to parse memory of the product.

ONEPLUS
9 Dual Sim Fizic 256GB 5G Mov Winter Mist 12GB RAM

SAMSUNG
Galaxy A02 Dual Sim Fizic 64GB LTE 4G Rosu 12GB RAM
64GB', '15GB

output: 256GB', '12GB
64GB', '12GB

How to spilt this 256GB', '12GB.
I want only 256GB and 64GB.
How to get the 64GB and 256GB using regex in python. gb may be small or caps.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re
import xlwt
from datetime import date

class quickmobile:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://www.quickmobile.ro/telefoane-si-accesorii/telefoane-mobile'
        self.country='IT'
        self.currency='lei'
        self.VAT='Included'
        self.shipping = 'free delievry if you are a VIP club member'
        self.color = 'N/A'
        self.Pre_PromotionPrice ='N/A'
    def quick_mobiles(self):
        wb = xlwt.Workbook()
        ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
        ws.write(0,0,"Product_Manufacturer")
        ws.write(0,1,"Product_Url")
        ws.write(0,2,"Product_Price")
        ws.write(0,3,"Product_Model")
        ws.write(0,4,"Memory")
        ws.write(0,5,"Currency")
        ws.write(0,6,"Color")
        ws.write(0,7,"VAT")
        ws.write(0,8,"Shipping Cost")
        ws.write(0,9,"Pre_PromotionPrice")
        ws.write(0,10,"Country")
        ws.write(0,11,"Date")
        ws.write(0,12,"Raw_Model")
        wb.save(r"C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\quickmobile.xls")
        driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(self.url)
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            titles = []
            models = []
            memorys = []
            prices = []
            product_links = []
            while True:  
                storage_box = []
                storage_box = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 sort col-md-4 col-lg-4 padd-mobile-card-product"]')
                for storage_boxes in storage_box:

                    product_url = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="card-body card-product-body"]')
                    product_urls = product_url.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                    print(product_urls)
                    product_links.append(product_urls)

                    manufacturer = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="card-product-title"]').text
                    print(manufacturer)
                    titles.append(manufacturer)

                    product_model = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('div.card-product-description').text
                    print(product_model)
                    models.append(product_model)
                    
                    memory = re.findall(r'\b\d{2,3}\s*gb\b',product_model,re.I)
                    product_memory = str(memory).replace("['",'').replace("']",'').replace("[]",'').strip()
                    print(product_memory)
                    if (product_memory == ""):
                        product_memory ='N/A'
                    memorys.append(product_memory)
                    print(product_memory)
                    product_price = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="priceFormat card-price"]').text
                    print(product_price)
                    prices.append(product_price)

                next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.right img')
                time.sleep(3)
                next.click()
                time.sleep(3)
                if driver.current_url == self.url:
                    break
            i=0
            while i<len(titles):
                ws.write(i+1,0,str(titles[i]))
                ws.write(i+1,1,str(product_links[i]))
                ws.write(i+1,2,str(prices[i]))
                ws.write(i+1,3,str(models[i]))
                ws.write(i+1,4,str(memorys[i]))                
                ws.write(i+1,5,str(self.currency))
                ws.write(i+1,6,str(self.color))
                ws.write(i+1,7,str(self.VAT))
                ws.write(i+1,8,str(self.shipping))
                ws.write(i+1,9,str(self.Pre_PromotionPrice))
                ws.write(i+1,10,str(self.country))
                ws.write(i+1,11,str(date.today()))
                ws.write(i+1,12,str(models[i]))
                i=i+1
                wb.save(r"C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\quickmobile.xls")
        except:
            pass    

quick_mobile = quickmobile()
quick_mobile.quick_mobiles()
```

Comment: it's good that you included code, but in this case most of it isn't part of the problem. Please remove everything but the part that extracts the memory from a string.

Comment: I would find all occurrences of `\d+ ?[gG][bB]`, convert the number to int and take the smaller one (I have never seen a phone with more RAM than flash. If you only find one I would take it as RAM if its's lower than 20GB (may change in the future)

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall("(?i)(\d+gb)', '(\d+gb)", "256GB', '12GB")`